# WPF fullscreen window with IWindowManager ShowWindow and settings

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro for my desktop WPF application and I've some issues with showing new window on fullscreen (WindowState.Maximized).

I try something like this:

```
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.Title = Resources.ManagementTitle;
settings.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
settings.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;            

_windowManager.ShowWindow(_myViewModel, null, settings);
```

And unfortunately my window appears but it is not a fullscreen. Other options (Title, ResizeMode) works just fine

And view of this window looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Project.View"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800" Width="1000" Height="600">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Any hints why window shows with state maximized but not fullscreen?

Regards